# What is the standard amount (if there is one) for a "glass" of wine?

Tags: wine

I have seen wine poured to various amounts in a wine glass; what amount is generally considered standard...4 oz, 6 oz, 8 oz?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It comes from two different measurements, typical wine bottle size, and government alcohol regulations

Typical wine bottles are 750 ml, and this divides exactly into five or six servings of 150 or 125 ml (thanks peter). So many traditional wine glass serves are "exactly" 150 or 125 ml (~5 or 4 oz) depending in which country you live in

For typical government regulation, a standard drink is; a 100 ml glass of table wine, or a 330 ml can of beer, or a 30 ml glass of straight spirits. Each of these contains on average 10 g of alcohol. So many liquor licensing guidelines recommend the serving of wine by 100 ml (3.5 oz) standard drink sizes

Governments will use this to produce such amazing guidelines such as:

```
For women: Two standard drinks a day, and no more than ten standard drinks a week
For men: Three standard drinks a day, and no more than fifteen standard drinks a week
And for both at least two alcohol-free days every week
```

In most western countries the standard drink range is from 8 to 12 g of alcohol, except in the USA where it is super-sized to 14 g

---

Update; references from [ICAP](http://www.icap.org/)

- [Standard drink sizes](http://www.icap.org/PolicyTools/ICAPBlueBook/BlueBookModules/20StandardDrinks/tabid/161/Default.aspx#1)
- [Drink Guidlines](http://www.icap.org/PolicyTools/ICAPBlueBook/BlueBookModules/19DrinkingGuidelines/tabid/179/Default.aspx#1)

Comment: Thank you TFD. A family friend who does not drink alcohol at all and additionally is apprehensive about consuming any substance in even the smallest amount, was advised by his physician to "drink a glass of wine each day".  He really has no idea how much is appropriate.  So the 750 ml bottle/ 5 -5 oz servings that you mentioned makes good sense to share with him so that he is comfortable with the doctor's orders.  Thanks for the detailed reply and helpful information :)

Comment: It's worth noting that not only is the size of the standard drink different depending on the country, the recommended intake is often different as well. For example, in Finland the standard drink is 12g or 15.2mL of alcohol, whereas in the US it's 14g or 17.7mL (for men). But the maximum recommended weekly intake in the US is 14 drinks or 247.8mL, whereas in Finland the maximum weekly recommended intake is 24 drinks or 364.8mL (for men). So this is often a confusing issue.

Comment: Wait, he was told by his physician to drink a glass of wine a day?  Clearly I have the wrong doctor!

Comment: For restaurant pours, it's also worth noting that this varies pretty significantly by region and current trend.  For example, San Francisco is currently in a $12, 9-oz-glass-of-wine mood.

Comment: @Melanie I don't drink either. Suggest you get your friend to go to another doctor for a second opinion. Alcohol is a strong physical and mental poison, there must be something simpler? Aspirin, Warfarin?

Comment: @TFD This man is critically ill& this is just one of many advisements given him by his treating physician(s).He's remained in pain& lacking mobility-due to fear of medicine- contributing to depression. (He recently began takingbaby aspirin) This causes dismay& concern for his spouse& friends. Ive heard other physicians suggest that red wine is actually good for us(most) due to high anti-oxidants-believed to be crucial in cancer prevention.This man's undergone surgery& chemo. I believe his HC team is searching for options to renew his strength& ability to fight against a cancer relapse.

Comment: I think the effect of antioxidants is speculative, but there is evidence that consuming alcohol (any type) in small amounts reduces the risk of heart disease, stroke, and possibly diabetes: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/is-alcohol-beneficial-in-small-amounts

Comment: I think that in the UK the standard size of a glass of wine is 125ml. I certainly picked up from somewhere the notion that a 75cl bottle is 6 glasses.

Comment: @TFD: alcohol can be a strong poison, sure. Warfarin, on the other hand, is the traditional pesticide against mice and rats... Remember, everything is poison, it just depends on the dose. Plus, medical advice on the Internet: plain wrong...

Comment: @nico that was "strong physical and mental poison". Warfarin does not cause significant mental changes :-)

Comment: One glass of wine probably won't cause significant mental changes either, unless you're rather light or deficient in certain enzymes. :P

Comment: @TFD - Comparing Warfarin and aspirin to wine in moderation is absurd.  Warfarin is highly dangerous and requires continuous monitoring; aspirin is only somewhat less dangerous.  Wine (red) in moderation, on the other hand, is not only harmless but has proven beneficial qualities.  Suggesting Warfarin and aspirin over a single glass of wine per day not only makes no sense medically but is downright irresponsible.

Comment: @CareyGregory I think you have miss read the comments. Yes, Aspirin, warfarin, AND alcohol are all poisons, and should be avoided if you don't need to have them

Comment: @TFD Almost everything is poison in sufficient quantity, including even water.  So designating three arbitrary substances "poisons" isn't helpful.  Red wine in moderation is beneficial, and _not_ harmful, so designating it a poison without qualifying that to add "in excess" is just flat wrong.  There are many physicians who actually prescribe red wine, including mine.

Comment: @CareyGregory Are they recommending red wine for the flavinoids or the alcohol? There is not much science out there showing a net gain from alcohol consumption

Comment: @TFD We don't disagree except in what I think is a rather overly prudish assessment of alcohol.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK it's either 175ml or 125 ml and confusion reigns, as bars will happily serve you a 250 mil and charge the large glass price!

I would tend to believe 175ml in restaurants and 125ml for medical advice.

Comment: 125ml was the standard measure in pubs and restaurants when I starting drinking. Then 175ml came in as a "large glass" of wine. Now 175ml is the normal almost everywhere, and 250ml is the "large glass". And, in the meantime, standard white wines have gone from 9-11% abv to typically 12.5% abv; and red has gone from 11-13% to 12.5-14.5%.

Answer (score 0):

125ml would be considered a standard amount in France.

Comment: Do you have a source for the 125ml figure? It would add a lot of credence to your answer.

Comment: Hello Gerlech, all discussions of health are off topic here. I had to remove that part of your answer and left the part which addressed the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

In Canada wine usually put on the menu as 6oz with the option for 9oz. Never worked anywhere that serves any other number, but once went to a restaurant which did 5oz, which was very unusual.