# Definition of a "half glass?"

Tags: italian-cuisine

I'm making oven baked caponata and the recipe calls for a half glass of vinegar.  No clue how many ounces to a "glass."

Comment: I'd guess it's equivalent of half of a glass of wine, but size of a "standard" glass of wine varies a bit. Anywhere from 100 ml to 175 ml according to the answers to this question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/23734/what-is-the-standard-amount-if-there-is-one-for-a-glass-of-wine

Comment: Alternately, some old recipes will use "glass" to mean [2 ounces](http://savoystomp.com/2008/07/21/savoy-cocktail-volume/).

Comment: You'd get better answers if you included more of the recipe, so people could get a better idea which of these suggestions is right. (The first comment suggests 50-88mL, the second suggests 30mL, and the third suggests 118mL, a pretty huge range.)

Answer (score 1):

From my years of cooking, I would guess this to be about 4 oz. or 1/4 C. as we sometimes used a small 8 oz. juice glass for measuring and half a glass would be half of that or 4 oz = 1/4 C., especially with vinegar, Other than pickles I could not imagine a recipe using more vinegar than that.  Hope this is helpful.